# When using SELECT can you modify the value of a returned field based on other fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

When using MySQL SELECT can you change the value of a returned field based on other fields?

For example, if I have this select:

```
SELECT city,state,country FROM table
```

Now if city is empty AND state is empty, I want the value of country to returned empty as well (whether country actually has a value or not).

Example table:

```
id | city | state | country
-----------------------------
1  | Here | There | MyCountry
2  |      |       | YourCountry
```

So with the above table, I want the results for id=1 to return Here,There,MyCountry but the results for id=2 should be empty,empty,empty

Thanks

**EDIT:** To clarify, a WHERE clause will not work because I need the row returned even if city and state are empty. A better example might have been SELECT id,city,state,country FROM my_table

Comment: To clarify - do you definitely want a row returned if there is no city or state data available?

Comment: yes i do need the row returned even if there is no city or state data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**(misprints corrected):

```
SELECT city,state,
CASE 
 WHEN (city IS NULL OR city='') AND (state IS NULL or state='') THEN ''
 ELSE country
END as country_1
 FROM `table`
```

You can also use `IF` instead of `CASE`:
  `IF ((city IS NULL OR city='') AND (state IS NULL or state=''),'',country) as country_1`

Comment: That's excellent... thank you! It's easy once you know what you are looking for! It's under Control Flow Functions here (from mysql v5 manual):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html
This is what I actually ended up doing:
SELECT city,state,if(city='' AND state='','',country) as country FROM table

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes; you're looking for what's called control flow functions.

Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Thanks... I found this prior to seeing your post, but definitely a good link to have!

Answer (score 1):

a1ex07 is right, but you need to fix a few query errors in his SELECT stmt.

first, there is a missing comma after "state" and second, if your table were really called "table" you have to enclose in backticks because it is a reserved MySQL keyword.

```
SELECT city,state, 
CASE 
 WHEN (city IS NULL OR city='') AND (state IS NULL or state='') THEN ''
 ELSE country
END as country_1
 FROM `table``
```

(exlude second backtick, stackoverflow uses those for syntax highlighting if single.)

Comment: Thanks for noticing correctons. No, my table name is not really table, I just used that for an example, but its a good reminder that it would need to be in backticks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a WHERE clause?

For example:

```
SELECT city, state, country FROM <table> WHERE (city <> "" OR state <> "");
```

N.B.: You'll need to replace the '<> ""' above with 'IS NOT NULL' if these are actually nulled rather than simply empty.

Comment: -1. That's not what the OP asked for; your query would return one row, his would return two.

Comment: @Adam Maras - So you're downvoting because I suggested an alternative (and perhaps more appropriate) answer than what the OP specifically asked for?

Comment: You can't call it more appropriate when the OP **specifically** asked for the query to return a certain way. OP was very clear about the intended functionality.

Comment: @middaparka: I think you need to correct your N.B. section: `city <> NULL` is not the right way to check if the value is null (actually, it's always false[or null to be precise])

Comment: @Adam Maras If you look at it that way, then the OP **specifically** used city,state,country in his SELECT clause - what's he going to do with three empty fields and no ID in the returned data?

Comment: @middaparka did you consider that it might be a truncated, simplified example that actually has other columns of data? In that case, it **will** have an ID and it will have other necessary data. You're right; a query that returns purely blank rows makes absolutely no sense. That's why it's likely that it's just a filtered-down example of what the OP's trying to do.

Comment: @Adam Maras Or (and here's where I've been going with this) perhaps the OP is a beginner, and wasn't aware of the fact that he could use a SELECT in the manner I've described above.

Comment: @middaparka: Thanks middaparka, but I still need it to return empty rows even when city and state are blank/empty which is why I could not use the WHERE clause. I see you asked that question above under my original question, but responded before I had a chance to answer it. @Adam Maras: I don't think you should downvote middaparka as his answer is relevant to the question as specifics were not given, and had I been a complete newb it might have been what I was looking for. This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I will try to provide more details in future questions that I ask. Thanks