# Select with custom result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have in database:

```
City:
id | name       | type
1  | London     | A
2  | Manchester | E
3  | Cardiff    | W
```

and i would like receive with select:

```
1  | London     | First
2  | Manchester | Second
3  | Cardiff    | Third
```

so query should replace A to First, E to Second and W to Third.

```
SELECT id, name, type ???? FROM City
```

How can i make it?

Comment: Will type "A" always be "First"?

Comment: Do you have another table where `A` `E` `W` are mapped to `First` `Second` and `Third`?

Comment: Have a look at [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using SELECT can you modify the value of a returned field based on other fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701462/when-using-select-can-you-modify-the-value-of-a-returned-field-based-on-other-fi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,
       name,
       case when type = 'A' then 'First'
            when type = 'E' then 'Second'
            when type = 'W' then 'Third'
       end as alias_name
from City
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a third table with the information for type.

```
 type | label
 A    | First
 B    | Second
 C    | Third
```

Having this tables you can easily join the needed information.

```
SELECT id, name, label FROM City LEFT JOIN `type_table` USING `type`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    IF(
        type = 'A', 'First',
    IF(
        type = 'E', 'Second',
    IF(
        type = 'W', 'Third', type))
) as type FROM City
```

I did a performance test and in this case several IF are faster than a WHEN

Comment: I did a performance test and in this case several IF are faster than a WHEN

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of commenting on it.