# When using SELECT, modify the value of a returned field based on row present in an other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to change the value in a SELECT (using MySQL) base on the if a row is present in an other table or not.

I have this questionnaire that allows to have multiple answer (a, b, c, d, etc.) and regular answers. Each question is store in a table called questionnaire and has a flag (0 or 1) if it's a multiple answer question (column name is multiple_answer).

If the flag equals 1, I want to get the information stored in `c.answer`. 
If it's equals to 0, I want to get the information stored in `a.answer`.

I have minimise my query to clearly show what I'm trying to achieve.

**EDIT 1** : Modified the IDs, and replaced the a, b, c variables.

```
SELECT participantAnswers.`id_question`, CASE 
              WHEN (`multiple_answer` = 1) 
              THEN questionsMultipleAnswers.`answer` 
              ELSE participantAnswers.`answer` 
            END 
FROM    (SELECT `id_question`, `answer` FROM `questionnaire_participant_answers`)participantAnswers, 
        (SELECT `id`, `id_category`, `question`, `multiple_answer` FROM `questionnaire`)questions,
        (SELECT `id_question`, `value`, `answer` FROM `questionnaire_answers`)questionsMultipleAnswers 
WHERE questions.`id` = a.`id_question` AND CASE 
              WHEN questions.`multiple_answer` = 1
              THEN participantAnswers.`id_question` = questionsMultipleAnswers.`id_question` AND participantAnswers.`answer` = questionsMultipleAnswers.`value`
            END
```

An output would be something like

```
id_question | answer  
-----------------------------
1           | multi-answer-q1-5
2           | multi-answer-q2-5
3           | multi-answer-q3-4
4           | simple-answer-q4
1           | multi-answer-q1-2
...         | ...
```

Is it possible to achieve this or I would have to create 2 different queries for this?

If it's not possible, I could easily live with something like :

```
id_question | multi-answer | simple-answer 
---------------------------------------------
1           | q1-5         |
2           | q2-5         |
3           | q3-4         |
4           |              | q4
1           | q1-2         |
...         | ...          | ...
```

PS - I inspired myself from this post [When using SELECT can you modify the value of a returned field based on other fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701462/when-using-select-can-you-modify-the-value-of-a-returned-field-based-on-other-fi)

**Edit 2** : Here is are real values

(multiple choice stored in participantAnswers)

```
id_question | questions                 | multiple_answer | parti-answer | ques-answer
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | Do you feel tired?        | 1               | 5            | Exhausted
2           | How is your mood ?        | 1               | 5            | Stressed
3           | How many hours of sleep ? | 1               | 4            | 6 to 7
```

(simple choice also stored in participantAnswers)

```
id_question | questions                 | multiple_answer | parti-answer 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           | What is your weight?      | 0               | 164.2
```

So to clarify, the answers are all in the same table. The problem I have is to create a query where I replace the `parti-anwser` for the `ques-answer` IF it's a multiple answer question.

Thank you for your time guys

Comment: How can one question (ID 1) have multiple answers and a regular simple answer at the same time? And you want to show the correct multi answers in case a question is a multi answer question, but the participants answer in case it is a simple single answer question?

Comment: BTW: Your derived tables make the query harder to read. As they have no criteria, it makes no sense to use derived tables. Moreover you should use explicit join syntax instead of listing comma separated tables as it was the custom twenty years ago. At last, don't use table aliases that have nothing to do with the tables. Aliases like a, b and c are not easy to read. Better use q for questionnaire, a or qa for questionnaire_answers, etc.

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what is being asked. does your query return any results, do you get an error? why existing answers in mentioned question do not work for you? What is the purpose of the CASE .. WHEN in the where clause?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for your time, I fixed the ids as you suggested and added more information in the Edit 2 (with real values from the DB). I hope it can help you.

Comment: @Bulat Thank you for your time. Yes the query does return something. It returns only the answers that are marked as multiple answers (1). The CASE .. WHEN in the WHERE (probably part of the problem) was to replace the `parti-answer` by the value of `quest-answer` (see Edit 2). That part works, it replace the value '4' by '6 to 7 hours'.

Comment: Sorry to say I still don't understand your data model and question. And neither do others it seems. Questions like yours usually get several answers within minutes when the question is clear. I recommend you go to sqlfiddle.com and enter your create table and insert statements, so we can see the database structure and some sample data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I will look in the option of sqlfiddle (didn't knew it existed). I'm pretty busy today so I will only post the code tonight and let you know when it's up there. I may have a design flaw in my database. I was in a rush when I created it, so that might be why it's not working in an easy way.